# Conda environment is not running as I expected

Tags: conda

I am using a new conda environment and playing around with Pytorch. I just want to make sure my GPU is running so then I run the code `print(torch.cuda.is_available())`. When I try to run the script, it returns False.

Command of running `test.py` image:
[image]

`test.py` code image:

[image]

However, when I run python on conda prompt, it returns True. I have no idea how this is possible.

Command image:
[image]

Can anybody tell me where I did wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Code and errors should always be posted as text rather than images

Comment: Hi, thank you! I am very new to asking questions on StackOverflow. Thanks for the reminder.